# Redirect URL to new address but keep the original

Tags: apache, http, url, redirect

I'd like to redirect certain URLs to a template page with the page being a $_GET variable. More specifically:

`http://domain/` & `http://domain/home` ==> `http://domain/main.php?page=home`
`http://domain/about` ==> `http://domain/main.php?page=about`

And I'd like certain words to redirect to another template, like so:
`http://domain/login` ==> `http://domain/uam.php?action=login`

What is the best way to achieve this?

Again, I'd like to keep the URLs that I'm redirecting from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure mod_rewrite is installed and loaded, make sure AllowOverride All is set in the VirtualHost section of your conf file, and put these lines in your .htaccess file in the document root of the web server.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ main.php?page=home [L]

RewriteRule ^login uam.php?action=login [L, QSA, NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ main.php?page=$1 [L, QSA, NC]
```